# Tail Recursion and Side effect

Tags: scala, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I am actually learning scala and I have a question about tail-recursion. Here is an example of factorial with tail recursion in scala :

```
    def factorial(n: Int): Int = {

    @tailrec
    def loop(acc: Int, n: Int): Int = {
      if (n == 0) acc
      else loop(n * acc, n - 1)
    }
    loop(1, n)
  }
```

My question is updating the parameter, `acc`  as we do it in the function `loop` can be considered as a side effect? Since in FP, we want to prevent or diminish the risk of side effect.

Maybe I get this wrong, but can someone explain to me this concept.

Thanks for your help

Comment: No it doesn't. Pure functions doesn't contain side effects by definition and loop is pure (it depends only on parameters passed in).

Comment: I believe that `@tailrec` should be moved to your `loop` function. Function `loop` is recursive, while `factorial` is not - it never calls itself, it only calls `loop`.

Comment: Thanks Petr, you are totally right !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You aren't actually changing the value of any parameter here (as they are `val`s by definition, you couldn't, even if you wanted to).

You are *returning a new value*, calculated from the arguments passed in (and only those). Which, as @om-nom-nom pointed out in his comment, is the definition of pure function.

Comment: That said, it's worth noting that it's not unusual for purely functional programs to use this sort of tail-recursive passing to emulate state.  Erlang in particular is known for eternally-runing processes that continually pass their state tail recursively to themselves, forever

Comment: It's not so much emulating state as saying explicitly what the concept of state means implicitly. If a (pure) function depends on computations that have already executed, those computations must have resulted in some values which are passed into the function through its arguments.